# Bootstrap Datetimepicker issue and other basic html/css positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

My main question is with the bootstrap datetimepicker.  I was using [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#minimum-setup) as a guide for using the bootstrap? datetimepicker.

After many attempts to get the guide to work, I came to the conclusion that the datetimepicker isn't included in the main bootstrap.js file.  After many searches, I couldn't find a js file that was "the" bootstrap datetimepicker, nor any that had a function defined as datetimepicker() as in the guide.  I also couldn't find anything on bootstraps website regarding a datetimepicker.  So my question is, is there such the as a bootstrap datetimepicker, or are there just js scripts meant to work with bootstrap?  Also, where can I get these files?

It finally occurred to me to just us chrome developer tools to get the url the guide was using for the script source.  Finally, I got this to kind of work as it does in the guide, but "appealing" way.  I can't seam to get the cursor to change to a finger pointing on mouseover.  Also, once the calendar is open, the cursor is still just the arrow, and clicking on a date does not close the calendar as in the guide.  Does anyone have any recommendations on how I can get this to work more like the tutorial?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"     href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script     src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrat/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <title>Rental Car Agreement</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: Oh okay I'm sorry.  Should I just edit this one to remove my second questions?  Thanks